# how can i make javascript syntax errors control in android studio. cordova project

Tags: javascript, android-studio, cordova

I have a cordova  project. And to correct errors i search them one by one building apk and running it in emulator each time to see one syntax error at a time in chrome dev inspect tool, turn back to android studio, fix, build, deploy and so on..

Believe there is a faster way. i tried to google, but for some reason there are no faqs about syntax control in js.